# Borders with captions in WPF

Tags: wpf, border, caption

Does anybody know how to get a border in WPF with a caption, i.e. the way web browsers display <fieldset> tags ?  Is there an easy way, like setting a property, or am I going to have to make a ControlTemplate ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Perhaps a [GroupBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.groupbox.aspx)?

```
<GroupBox>
    <GroupBox.Header>
      <Label>Hello</Label>
    </GroupBox.Header>
    <TextBlock Text="World!" />
</GroupBox>
```